# Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String?' with Tableview in (cellForRowAt)

Tags: arrays, string, uitableview, int

I'm trying to to assign a value which is an Int to the cell Label in (cellforRowAt) but how do I convert 'members' to a String? 'Members' is an Int declared in a struct. Any ideas for how to convert the String to Int in the tableview function?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! ClassesTBVCustomCell
        cell.className.text = myClass[indexPath.row].className
        cell.userCountLabel.text = myClass[indexPath.row].**members**

        cell.cellView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cell.delegate = self

        return cell
    }
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String?'
```

And here is where 'members' is declared:

```
struct ClassData {

    let postId: String
    let members: Int
    let className: String
    init?(postId: String, dict: [String: Any]) {
        self.postId = postId

        guard let members = dict["members"] as? Int,
            let className = dict["className"] as? String
            //let classPosts = dict["classPosts"] as? String
            else { return nil }
        self.members = members
        self.className = className
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this one.... String(myClass[indexPath.row].members)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `members` variable from int to string in following way to show:-

```
let member = "\(myClass[indexPath.row].members)"
cell.userCountLabel.text = member
```